# Different ways for earning reputation on Stack Exchange websites

Tags: discussion, reputation

I am new on Stack Overflow and am looking for ways to increase the reputation of my profile.

In general, I am looking for getting the chat on Stack Overflow enabled.

Comment: see also on the Network-wide Meta: [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't rush into the game of reputation of Stack Overflow. Rather be good to the community and help others by answering their questions, chatting with people, editing, and correcting mistakes in other's text.

Do all these tasks and you'll definitely get what you're looking for.

P.S. Sign in with this same account on other SE websites and you'll get more reputation points. If I am not wrong then it is +1 for every signup.

Comment: You don't get any rep just for joining other SE sites with one account. What you _do_ get is a 100 point bonus once you reach 200 points on one of the sites (association bonus).

Comment: @Bill Tür: Don't you get 1 (not 0)? (Though the total network-wide reputation only shows up in one of the "[flair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7SNEdjftno)"s(?))

Comment: @PeterMortensen You're correct, one starts with 1 point if they join a site. But this doesn't have any influence on other sites. I meant my comment in the context of OP's statement that one gets more rep if they join other sites. So to claryfiy: one doesn't get any rep on Stack Overflow just by joining for example Super User. Sorry if my comment was misleading (but as far as I've seen you around here I guess you knew that anyway ;-) )